# Plot with non-standard domain

Tags: plotting

I have data `{x, y}` where x starts at -25 degrees and goes up to +25 degrees in 1 degree steps, and then comes back down to -25 degrees in 1 degree steps again.

I want to plot this sinusoidal-type data without the y-data overlapping in the ranges -25 - +25 degrees.  I have attached an image of the kind of graph  I am after.

[image]

How does one do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always use Manual `Tick` specifications:

```
ticks = Join[Range[-25, 25, 5], Range[20, -25, -5]];
data = Table[{x, RandomInteger[10]}, {x, ticks}];
```

now the plot. the [[;; ;; 2]] selects just every second tickmark. Note that I plot the y-data just against their index and not against their x-value.

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All, 2]],  
  Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range@Length[data], ticks}][[;; ;; 2]], Automatic}]
```

[image]